# Can't find module with sqlite3 with Node on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I get the following error with "nodejs server.js"

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/domain/mydomain.photos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/relive/relive.photos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

The problem is that in "'/home/domain/mydomain.photos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/" i do not have a node-v11-linux-x64, but rather node-v46-linux-x64.

I am using Nodejs v0.10.25 and Sqlite v3.8.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to delete this directory (node_modules/sqlite3) and reinstall sqlite3 again?

Comment: @risyasin yes many times. Any other ideas?

Comment: @risyasin do you think the problem is with sqlite3 or the system?

Comment: Well, have no idea but sounds like a dev lib is missing in your system. maybe "libsqlite3-dev"? can't reproduce here :/  as far i know node-sqlite3 uses node-gyp to compile.